# Microsoft App certification process can not be cancelled

Tags: windows, uwp

A submission has been in the certification phase for more than 2 weeks, and it can't be cannelled. The dashboard says a few but could be up to 3 days. 
I tried to cancel the submission serveral times, nothing changed. The certification is always at "Pre-processing".

Comment: You clicked the button that reads *"Ask Question"* but then decided not to. Why?

Comment: @IInspectable, What do you mean? What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) locally to see if it passes there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit 
If the tests fail locally, you'll have an error report describing what problem(s) occurred.
If WACK tests pass locally, but certification fails/hangs in the dashboard, without showing any error report, you'll likely need support from the dashboard team who can look into the specific package and find out why it's stuck. You can loop them in by going to http://aka.ms/storesupport, selecting contact us, and then choose the Dasbhoard topic, App submissions issue type, and package management subcategory. There's options to chat or submit an incident there. They should be able to tell you why it's failing.

Comment: I contacted the support team, after about one week, the issue was resolved. Thank you for your answer sincerely.